# Batch rename files with regex not working

Tags: regex, linux

I've got many files on a linux server which have this format
`text_text_mixturelettersnumbers.file`for example `Hesperocyparis_goveniana_E00196073A.bam.bai`or `Hesperocyparis_forbesii_RBGEH19_bwa_out.txt`. I would like to change the first underscore to a hyphen and leave everything else so it looks like this `text-text_mixturelettersnumbers.file`.

I have tried `rename -n 's/(\w+)_(\w+_.)/$1-$2/' *` and many different versions thereof but nothing is happening. Could someone please point out what I've got wrong?

Thanks

Markus

Comment: This command is working fine

Comment: There are two tools out there named `rename`, one from util-linux and one written in Perl. Your syntax looks like the util-linux one, but check `rename --version` to make sure.

Comment: @Thomas given the `s///` I'd guess it's the perl one.

Comment: @jhnc Uh, yes, absolutely right, not sure what I was thinking.

Comment: perl version: `rename s/_/-/ ?*_?*_?*` ; util-linux version: `rename _ - ?*_?*_?*`. Note that `-n` means "don't do anything"...

Comment: I just realised that I've got the util-linux and not the perl version - no wonder it didn't work. Is there a way to see what the command would do without actually doing it? I thought that -n is that option listing the original and renamed files on screen. I'd hate to mess up dozens of file names in a oner...

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`util-linux` *rename*](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) does not have an option to display the results only. It is very basic.

If you want to list the files that contain two underscores before an extension, use

```
for f in *_*_*.*; do
  echo "$f => ${f/_/-}";
done
```

To actually rename, use `mv`:

```
for f in *_*_*.*; do
  mv -- "$f" "${f/_/-}";
done
```

The `"${f/_/-}"` replaces the first `_` with `-` in variable `f`.

Comment: When I use the above command with `echo` then it does exactly what I want it to do. However, when I want to carry it out with `mv`then I get the following error `mv: missing destination file operand after 'Xanthocyparis_vietnamensis_E00160382A.fasta => Xanthocyparis-vietnamensis_E00160382A.fasta'`. Where would I have to insert the destination folder when all the files are in the destination folder already?

Comment: @Markus No idea what the issue is, I know that there can be issues when files start with a hyphen, so I added `--` after `mv`. Make sure you type the command correctly, and there are regular (not hard/soft) spaces between the command and arguments.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Adding `--` made all the difference. I copied and pasted the `echo` command first to see what's happening and then replaced `echo` with `mv` not noticing that there is also the `--` after it...